# Calling wcf from JQuery in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-parts

I have a wcf service hosted in SharePoint, I am trying to calling from a webpart like this:

```
function GetItem(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'htp://myserver:1111/sites/test/_layouts/15/myservice.svc/GetMyItem',
data: '{"ID":"1"}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(msg){
     alert(msg.d);
                      } ,
error:function(msg2){
     alert(msg2.statusText);
     return;
         }
  });        
    }
```

But I keep getting to the error section. when I browse to the htp://myserver:1111/sites/test/_layouts/15/myservice.svc/GetMyItem/1 I can get a file of type JSON, with this text inside: {"ID":"1", "title":"Item Title"}

is the problem with my service? or with my $.ajax code? should I use post or get? any idea will be good, thanks

Any help?! P.S: I wrote htp instead of http because I can't write http in this forum!

Comment: Should you use `post` or `get` for `GetMyItem`. What do you think??

Comment: I don't know! I want to pass parameter to the wcf service, and get back item from SharePoint, what should I use?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. If you are "getting" stuff, then use `get`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work with post is because with post, jQuery appends your `data` to the request body, whereas your web method expects this data in the url.

Try just concatenating the url with parameters.

`url: 'htp://myserver:1111/sites/test/_layouts/15/myservice.svc/GetMyItem/1',`

Comment: it tells me now: Method not allowed. 

Should I revert it back to GET?

Comment: @user2528662 You never said it was `GET` originally. In your code, it is `POST`. At this point, I suggest reading tutorials on how to use jquery ajax with WCF, since it appears there are multiple issues.

Comment: It wasn't GET originally, I actually have no idea if to set it to GET or POST, some articles online use POST and others use GET, I just want to pass the parameter from my aspx page to this wcf, this is why I am asking this question. Which approach should I use

Answer (score 0):

I could make it happen using GET method only with writing a little bit of client object model to get the link dynamically.